# Wpf Datagrid bindind selected value with value path

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datagrid

I have a problem with Datagrid SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath.

The Datagrid definition is the following:

```
   <DataGrid x:Name="dataGridResources" 
    SelectionUnit="FullRow" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedElement.Resource, Mode=TwoWay, 
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedValuePath="Resource">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tags" Binding="{Binding TagLine}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Resource" Binding="{Binding Resource}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

The Datagrid ItemsSource is bindinded to a property of the ViewModel (ElementsCVS.View) defined as CollectionViewSource for other reasons, anyway here's the code:

```
    elements = new ObservableCollection<MElement>();
    Elements = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Element>(elements);
    ElementsCVS = new CollectionViewSource();
    ElementsCVS.Source = Elements;
    ElementsCVS.View.Filter += ResourcesCVS_Filter;
```

An Element class is the base implementation of this interface:

```
    public interface IElement
    {
         string Name { get; set; }
         CustomType Owner { get; set; }
         int Order { get; set; }
         OtherCustomType Type { get; set; }
         string Resource { get; set; }
         string TagLine { get; }
    }
```

The actual items in the collection can be any child type.
The behaviour I want to achieve is that when we change the selection in datagrid its resource property value is assigned to the SelectedElement.Resource. The important note is that SelectedElement is not the current datagrid selection but it's bound to a different UI element selection and we need to keep all his other properties as they are.

Moreover inspecting the datagrid at runtime its selectedvalue property is updated accordingly selection on datagrid but I couldn't find a way to reflect that change on the SelectedElement's Resource property.

Any idea? Where am I wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance.

***EDIT***

As an example:

Let's say I have the following SelectedElement:

```
    { Name: Selected, Owner: SomeOwner, Order: 5, Type: 3, 
    Resource: "C:/Data/Res1.txt", TagLine: "Resource, C#, WPF" }
```

Then I selected the following item in DataGrid:

```
    { Name: Resxyz, Owner: null, Order: -1, Type: 3,
    Resource: "D:/Data/ResourceFile.txt", TagLine: "Resource, C++" }
```

At this point I want the SelectedElement to look like this:

```
    { Name: Selected, Owner: SomeOwner, Order: 5, Type: 3, 
    Resource: "D:/Data/ResourceFile.txt", TagLine: "Resource, C#, WPF" }
```

So the only action should be:

```
    SelectedElement.Resource = "D:/Data/ResourceFile.txt";
```

Comment: Can you add an example or something what you want and where your problem is ?

Comment: @SeeuD1 I edited as you requested, let me know if you need something else to be able to help me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, and that was stupid, my bad. The OnPropertyChanged event of the SelectedElement property was raised with mispelled property name.